# Restore permissions on /usr?

Tags: macos, permission

Through a series of unfortunate events I managed to run:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr
```

on my 10.10.5 machine. This has left it in an awkward state. I can no longer `sudo` commands as `sudo` is no longer owned by root on the machine.

I tried booting in to single user mode and `chown`'ing `/usr` back to `root:wheel` but `/usr` is a read-only file system in single user mode.

Apart from a total reinstall of OS X on the machine, is there anything else I can do to get the permissions on `/usr` back to `root:wheel`?

Comment: Did you try running `mount -u -w /` after booting to single user mode? Should remount the drive in read/write mode.

Comment: And, if you chown'ed everything, can't you just run `chown root /usr/bin/sudo`? It's your file and directory after all currently :-)

Comment: @patrix figured out the first bit just before you commented. :) Uh...I never thought to try the second suggestion. Myopic panic-induced tunnel vision as I screwed up my work laptop. :)

Comment: Not sure whether it will work though, maybe the set-user-ID flag gets killed which is required for sudo to work.

Comment: I'm not sure it would have worked either. I can't `chown` any other file I own to root. That seems slightly dangerous if it were possible.

Comment: Ah, right, good point. Anyway, good for you to have your system back :-)

Comment: Too bad SIP didn't have your back - this can't happen on 10.11 out of the box 

Comment: @bmike I have other feelings about SIP. See site chat! :D

Answer (score 3):

Managed to make `/` writeable by running

```
mount -uw /
```

in single-user mode and then I was able to repair the permissions with:

```
chown -R root:wheel /usr
```

Comment: So cool the system is sane enough to boot in single user mode and work. Recovery HD has terminal as well, but single user is faster when it works.